# Unable to change custom keyboard allowance

Tags: ios, xcode, custom-keyboard, ios-extensions

I would like to disable custom keyboards in various areas of my app. I have implemented `application(_:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier)` in my app delegate and conditionally allow extensions with the `UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier` identifier. However, I am unable to change this allowance after the first call to `application(_:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier)`. For example, if I return `false` on the first call to `application(_:shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier)` and return `true` on a second call, custom keyboards stay disabled in my app.

Comment: the `shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier` is an app settings not per text input.